# How to reference a extended subclass in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, extend, super

I am currently working on a project for java and the teacher isn't very great at explaining himself. 
Currently I'm stuck trying to reference an extended Class in java to get the balance. (i'm trying to edit the balance so that it can be displayed and changed in the array.

my main account looks like this

```
public class Account {
    private String name;
    private double quantity, price;
    private double rate;
    private Asset[] Asset;
}
```

The account that is extended is

```
abstract public class Asset {

    String symbol;


    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    protected Asset(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

}
```

The extensions look like so;

```
public class Cash extends Asset {

    private double Quantity;


    public Cash(double Quantity, String symbol) {
        super(symbol);
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }


    @Override
    public String getSymbol() {
        return super.getSymbol(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public double getQuantity() {
        return Quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(double Quantity) {
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
    } 
}
```

Now lets say I have a test instance created of class Account. 
How would I be able to edit the Cash value  from the Class account? (Main arg)
Here are the other extensions I have too just for reference.

```
public class Stock extends Asset {

    private String name;
    private double quantity, rate;


    public Stock(String name, double quantity, double rate, String symbol) {
        super(symbol);
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.rate = rate;
    }



    @Override
    public String getSymbol() {
        return super.getSymbol(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

If it helps, how would I be able to change the values in the extended classes? 
I've tried

```
Asset[0] = new Cash(25000.00,string);
```

but that's only helpful in putting the value manually.
Apologies for any mistakes, I'm pretty new to coding and java in general.

Comment: More fundamentally, don't. If you need to know that your `Cash` is a `Cash`, then treat it as a `Cash`, not a generic `Asset`.

Comment: It needs to be one, requirement from professor.

Comment: Then use the answer provided, but be aware that this is a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

The way you named your Asset array is confusing, java is case sensitive so name it for example:

```
private Asset[] asset;
```

You need to get a reference of the right type through casting before you can access it's own methods. You can do for example:

```
if (asset[0] instanceof Cash) {
   Cash cash = (Cash)asset[0];
   // Then you can access the setQuantity method
   cash.setQuantity(25000.00);
}
```

Comment: User.setQuantity(25000.00);
          System.out.println(User.getQuantity()); when i run this, it doesn't display anything (User being the instance of the Account class). Was wondering if I forgot something

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException I keep getting :\

Comment: @vdefile Then you forgot to initialize your variable. And always start Java variable names with lowercase.